# lambda expressions support in android eclipse

Tags: java, android

I am using the Eclipse from the ADT bundle , and i wanted to play with the Lambda expressions in separate java projects.I have installed and imported JDK8 , but eclipse keeps complaining about the lambda syntax and can't make it work.Are the lambdas support at all with this Eclipse distribution ?

```
public class test  {
interface test11 {
  int sum(int tur1, int tur2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


   int firstname;
   test11 kob =(t1,t2)-> {return t1+t2;};
   }
 }
```

it gives like "t1 cannot be resolved to variable etc"

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Eclipse is found in your ADT bundle? There should be solutions for 4.3.2 and some builds of 4.4 out there, via update site.

Comment: Seems that it is not supported, see https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler

Comment: hi , thanks , i will just download the standart edition then

Comment: I did that last Thursday (2013-05-01) and had best luck with eclipse-SDK-4.4M6 and the update site http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4-I-builds . The nightly build for Mac was badly broken for me.